# Snowflake Pay as you go

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have few questions regarding using snowflake in pay as you go model.

1. What is the process of setting up snowflake in pay as you go model on AWS cloud?
2. I saw snowflake is available on AWS marketplace, if I want to do pay as you go model for snowflake on AWS do I need to subscribe to snowflake on AWS Marketplace?
3. Why Snowflake documentation doesn't talk at all about snowflake on AWS marketplace? What is the difference between snowflake trail on signup.snowflake.com compared to snowflake on AWS marketplace? when to use which one?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @user15392044, have you considered contacting Snowflake for this sort of matter already? I bet they would love to get in touch with a potential new customer and therefore provide exhaustive explanations.https://www.snowflake.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have/need features from AWS account, the easiest way is go to Snowflake.com, and create a trial account. You can add a credit cart that will turn it into a paid account after 30 days or exceed $400 trial credits.

As part of the sign up, you specify which cloud and region you want

You don't need an AWS account.